# Create factory from static factory method, then call static factory method on that id

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I can create an object from a static factory object like so:

```
<bean id="myFactory" class="com.myco.MyFactory1" factory-method="createFactory">
  <constructor-arg value="aString" />
</bean>
```

Now I want to use the id 'myFactory' to call its <strike>static</strike> 'createFactory' method.

In java something like:

```
ObjectFactory objectFactory = MyFactory.createFactory().createFactory(); //Last createFactory method returns type ObjectFactory
```

Comment: didn't understand. You want something like MyFactory.createFactory().createFactory()` ?

Comment: Yes, MyFactory.createFactory().createFactory().  I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Maybe you need to clarify what you're trying to accomplish. If createFactory creates the factory, why would you want to create another factory? Don't you already have it?

Comment: +1 for clarification I thought being abstract would be better but when I don't know what I'm doing, not so much. So the last edit is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call factory methods on bean instances, but in this case the factory method must not be static.

```
<bean id="myFactory2" factory-bean="myFactory" factory-method="createFactory">

</bean>
```

Anyway, I agree to the others. You need to specify the requirement in detail. If your first com.myco.MyFactory1 returns an instance of com.myco.MyFactory1, it does not make much sense to call its createInstance method. As the same class is returned, the same static method will be called.

If your first factory com.myco.MyFactory1 returns instances of different classes, you can use the code from above to call factory-methods on these. But remember they have to be non static in this case.

UPDATE:

It is possible to create the new instance by calling a static method on another bean instance as follows.

```
 <bean id="myFactory2" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
   <property name="targetObject"><ref local="myFactory"/></property>
   <property name="targetMethod"><value>createFactory</value></property>
 </bean>
```

Nevertheless you should perhaps rethink your design.

Comment: This answered the question, unfortunately for me the question was wrong: I now need to ask Create factory from static factory method, then call <del>static</del> factory method on that id. Following what you've provided I still have an error.

Comment: @Quaternion - if the 2nd method is static, why do you need the first one?

Comment: I didn't I updated the question to reflect that I the second method was NOT static... so in effect changed the whole question, so I created a new one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475495/issue-wiring-an-entitymanager-from-entitymanagerfactory I couldn't change _this_ question from under those who have already solved it! (even if it wasn't what I needed solved).

Answer (score 2):

That is invalid Java code. It assumes your `MyFactory` has two methods with the same name - one `static` and one non-static. And this is not possible.

In case you are invoking the same static method twice, or invoking a method on another object - well, you can easily invoke it only once / merge the two invocations, into a, say `createObjectFactory()`

Furthermore, it seems really odd to create a factor which in turn creates a factory which in turn creates another factory. Sounds like a bad design (overdesign).

Comment: Couldn't MyFactory instantiate a FooFactory which has a static method which creates the object I really need?

Comment: yes, I included an update about that. Having 3 factories is just wrong